# The mathematical heritage of Lewis Carroll

Tags: math-history, big-list

Which mathematical results has Lewis Carroll, the author of *Alice's Adventures in Wonderland*, produced? [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lewis_Carroll#Mathematical_work) is very vague with regard to this topic and gives us little more than a matrix identity connected with his name.

I would be especially interested in his most important theorems on mathematical logic.

Comment: [This article](http://math.ucdenver.edu/~wcherowi/courses/m4010/s08/erdodgson.pdf) should be of some use.